Why is my php form only working for certain emails and not all contact submissions?
I utilized a client's contact form email for their website since my standard one didn't work on her site. Now, she's receiving a few form submissions, such as mine and a random, but when I submit using my personal email or she from hers, she's not receiving the contact form email at all.
What's wrong with this code that it's not sending? Happy to provide whatever additional code you need (e.g. the form).
The PHP script (mail.php)
function stripFormSlashes($arr)
    {
        if(!is_array($arr))
        {
            return stripslashes($arr);
        }
        else
        {
            return array_map('stripFormSlashes', $arr);
        }
     }
 
     if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
     {
        $_POST = stripFormSlashes($_POST);
     }
  $message = "";
  $message .= "First Name: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br \>\n";
  $message .= "Last Name: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br \>\n";
  $message .= "Email: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br \>\n";
  $message .= "Phone: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['telephone'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br \>\n";
  $message .= "Company: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['company'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br \>\n";
  $message .= "Comments: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br \>\n";
  $lowmsg = strtolower($message);
  $injection_strings = array ( "content-type:","charset=","mime-version:","multipart/mixed","bcc:","cc:");
  foreach($injection_strings as $suspect)
  {
   if((stristr($lowmsg, $suspect)) || (stristr(strtolower($_POST['first_name']), $suspect)) || (stristr(strtolower($_POST['email']), $suspect)))
   {
     die ( 'Illegal Input.  Go back and try again.  Your message has not been sent.' );
   }
  }
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: \"" . $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'] . "\" <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
  mail("emailtosendto@customdomain.com", "Contact Form Submission", $message, $headers);
  header("Location: ../thank_you.html");
?>

The form modal
<div
            class="modal fade"
            id="contactForm"
            data-bs-backdrop="static"
            data-bs-keyboard="false"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="contactFormLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
        >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div
                        class="modal-header border-0"
                        style="background-color: var(--tp-theme-main-bg)"
                    >
                        <h2
                            class="modal-title fs-5"
                            id="ContactFormLabel"
                            style="font-size: 36px !important"
                        >
                            Contact Me!
                        </h2>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn-close"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close"
                        ></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body form-group col-12 px-5">
                        <p>
                            contact text
                        </p>
                        <form
                            action="./assets/mail.php"
                            method="POST"
                            id="contactForm"
                        >
                            <div class="row g-3">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-item">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="first_name"
                                            placeholder="First Name"
                                            required
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-item">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="last_name"
                                            placeholder="Last Name"
                                            required
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-item">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="company"
                                            placeholder="Company Name"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-item">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="email"
                                            placeholder="Email Address"
                                            required
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-item">
                                        <input
                                            type="tel"
                                            name="telephone"
                                            placeholder="(555) 123-4567"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="input-item-textarea">
                                        <textarea
                                            name="message"
                                            placeholder="Let us know what you're looking for"
                                            required
                                        ></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer border-0 me-auto flex-row-reverse flex-md-row">
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                >
                                    Close
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    name="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-primary"
                                    style="position: relative"
                                >
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

I've tried to change the FROM around a bit to see if maybe that was causing issues, but that seems to just kill the submissions completely.

Check for errors. That said, deliverability is likely the culprit here. Use a proper SMTP server (Mailgun, SES, Sendgrid, Postmark, etc.) to send your mail more reliably, there's a good chance her mail server is outright rejecting it.

Does your SMTP server allow you to send emails using any from address? Mine doesn't, because that would be allowing Open Relay. You need to send the email from a known email address that your SMTP server does allow, and use the Reply-To header for the users email address. You might find it more reliable to use a library such as PHPMailer rather than the built-in PHP mail() function.

enable error logs to check why email fails. you can enable by adding lines in top of your file
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

and also you try to change you injection string code like below
$injection_strings = array(
    "content-type:", "mime-version:", "boundary=", "bcc:", "cc:", "to:", "from:", "reply-to:"
);
foreach ($injection_strings as $suspect) {
    if (preg_match("/" . preg_quote($suspect, '/') . "/i", $lowmsg) ||
        preg_match("/" . preg_quote($suspect, '/') . "/i", strtolower($_POST['first_name'])) ||
        preg_match("/" . preg_quote($suspect, '/') . "/i", strtolower($_POST['email']))) {
        die('Illegal Input.  Go back and try again.  Your message has not been sent.');
    }
}


you try to change you injection string code like below...why? Always explain your answer, don't just ask people to blindly apply any code you give them without knowing how it would help. See also [answer]
